# Looping through an array in SQL column

Tags: mysql, arrays, select, where-clause, mysql-json

I have a SQL table that looks something like this:

```
| ID  | Value                                                 |
| --- | ----------------------------------------------------- |
| 1   | {"name":"joe", "lastname":"doe", "age":"34"}          |
| 2   | {"name":"jane", "lastname":"doe", "age":"29"}         |
| 3   | {"name":"michael", "lastname":"dumplings", "age":"40"}|
```

How can I using SQL select function, select only the rows where "age" (in value column) is above 30?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the DBMS?

Comment: The DBMS used is MySQL

Comment: What's the data type of that column?

Comment: Datatype of "Value" column is "longtext".

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: SELECT VERSION(); returns the following: 5.7.36-cll-lve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column `Value` as it is it contains valid JSON data.
You can use the function `JSON_EXTRACT()` to get the the age and convert it to a numeric value by adding `0`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(Value, "$.age") + 0 > 30;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7b5ca13762bffd980d167fad92011bb).